# jQuery is blocked on some webpages for Chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

We are developing a chrome extension which loads a JS file from our server on any of the web page that starts an annotation system on the web page.

Further the JS file loads different scripts and style sheets using:

```
    xxx.prototype.loadScript = function(name, callback) {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = this.baseURL + "/js/" + name + "?id="+Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000); // Cache ID
      if (callback != null)
        this.addEvent(script, 'load', callback, false);
      alert(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)+ " ="+ name);
    }
```

My problem is that, jQuery is being loaded by this method inside the first JS file. The extension works well for most of the web pages but some of the pages as http://www.nytimes.com/ does not load the extension, rather it complaint that

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

at some lines down in the JS file that loads other scripts.

I tried to debug using alerts in the entry of the JS file and I saw no alert is being fired on this page where on other pages the alerts are fired and system works well.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to look into namespacing and the dollar alias. Are your scripts wrapped in a function that passes dollar? It's likely that it's already in use, possibly by the Prototype library.

Comment: be sure that when you need jquery (your scripts) jquery's script are already loaded (have a look at the developper console)

Comment: The main question is why do you inject the script in the webpage itself instead of doing the job in a content script which runs in "the isolated world" so that you don't have to worry about the conflicting variables?

Comment: Can you give an example of how I load an external plugin in the content script. I said my plugin can run on any web page using the Chrome extension for which the chrome extension injects one of the entry JS file in the web page's head. How can I achieve it using content script?

Comment: @nicol, I tried loading it with different ways, using jQuery no-conflicts too. But its not working.